# Проблема с запросом в вордпрес на выборку по категорям

Tags: wordpress

Нужно выбрать записи по нескольким критериям, один из которых принадлежность записи к нескольким рубрикам, одна из которых родительская 9 и другие дочернии 10,11.

Имеется вот такой запрос:

```
$query_string1 = "select p.*
from $wpdb->posts as p, 
$wpdb->postmeta as m1, $wpdb->term_relationships as m2, $wpdb->postmeta as m3
WHERE p.ID = m2.object_id and p.ID = m1.post_id and p.ID = m3.post_id 
and p.post_type='place' and m2.term_taxonomy_id in ('9,10,11')
and m3.meta_value='38' and m3.meta_key='school'
and (m1.meta_value LIKE \"%,$multi_city_id,%\") and m1.meta_key = 'post_city_id'
and p.post_status='publish'
order by p.post_title ASC";
```

Проблема в том, что запрос работает только когда запись принадлежит рубрике 9, одной, или в комбинации с любой другой рубрикой. Но если запись принадлежит исключительно дочерним рубрикам, то запрос ничего не выбирает. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: m2 у вас не связана никак с постами. покажите ее структуру.
И отформатируйте код. Нечитаемо.
Подозрительные кавычки ``'9,10,11'``

Comment: Без кавычек вообще не работает. А почему вы решили, что m2 никак не связана с постами, когда это таблица рубрик?

Comment: с m2 все в порядке, да. сложно воспринимать запрос в одну строку. по рубрикам: запрос не делит рубрики на "родительские" и "дочерние", смотрите таблицу m2, выбираются посты у которых рубрики имеют 9,10 или 11. по кавычкам: обычный sql принял бы это как одно зачение, притом строчное, а не три.

попробуйте отладить запрос в phpmyadmin'е, на второй взгляд ошибок нету...

Comment: еще есть вариант, что ищите по term_taxonomy_id а надо по term_id, которые бывают 9,10,11. часто они совпадают, но необязательно... в общем надо смотреть содержание таблиц чтоб понять что и как.

Comment: Таблица term_relationships единственная с которой можно связать по Id записи, а в ней есть только поле term_taxonomy_id. В phpmyadmin'е запрос работает так же - если рубрика 9 есть, то выбираются записи, если её нет, то он просто не видит записей.
Чёт голову уже сломал..

Comment: имел в виду, что сами рубрики - это term_taxonomy, а term_relationships - это развязочная таблица между постами и категориями. соответственно не хватает еще одной связи.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая связь видится верной.

```
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id in (9,10,11)
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY wposts.ID DESC
LIMIT $post_num
```

Comment: Уже лучше)) Происходит задубление вывода записей, во сколько категорий указано, столько раз и выведет. И мне еще нужно было условие по таблице postmeta наложить, а тут её вообще нет.

Comment: естественно. это запрос, иллюстрирующий связи, ограничения нужно добавить по необходимости. в документации пишут про три таблицы, в которых описана логика рубрик, соответственно те id, которые вы берете в качестве id категорий должны соответствовать категориям, а не id из развязочных таблиц...

По поводу distinct, ну да, просто вы писали что запрос не работает, а как именно не уточняли...